# extracting week day in text format from timestamp in logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

i am getting @timestamp in my logstash filter in below format

```
"@timestamp" => "2016-11-28T19:19:05.627Z"
```

i want to extract weekday and  month value in text format by adding a new field for week and month . my output should be like

```
week-day:monday
month:nov
```

i am using some ruby code

```
ruby {
          code => '
              require "time"
              event["week-day"] = event["@timestamp"].strftime "%a"

              '
       }
```

but getting error

```
Ruby exception occurred: undefined method `strftime' for "2016-11-28T19:19:05.804Z":LogStash::Timestamp {:level=>:error}
```

is there any way to do same in grok or in same ruby code?

any help ll be appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, you're just missing a little something:

```
   ruby {
      code => '
          require "time"
          event["week-day"] = event["@timestamp"].time.strftime "%a"
          '
   }
```

Comment: yea i was not converting that to time. it worked..Thanks  @Val